# Raspberry PI as printer

Tags: windows, printing, usb, raspberry-pi

I am wondering whether RasPI can be connected to a Windows PC through USB and appear to Windows as a printer. I want to process the PRINT command from Windows differently, say send that data to a webservice rather than printing it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible, but difficult.

There is a more simple method to do this: Just use a network printer (either samba or ipp) and do something with the sent postscript (e.g.) data. You might use your raspberry pi along with a installation of cups and a printer to serve this virtual network printer.

This way the windows host will handle the virtual printer just like a regular (network-)printer and you will not have to do any driver programming.

If you really want to use usb, then you have to face at least these difficulties:

- The raspberry pi itselves does not provide client-usb
- You have to choose or to create (don't do this!) a printer language (ps, pdf, ...)
- You perhaps have to interpret the data on the raspberry side and convert it to something else the webservice can handle.

Comment: Here's a reference to accomplish @urzeit first suggestion http://www.thelinuxcauldron.com/2013/12/01/how-to-using-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-cups-print-server/